# Different value in PowerBi chart per drillthrough level

Tags: sql, powerbi, reporting, business-intelligence

A productivity chart consists of a three level date hierarchy (1) year, (2) month, (3) week as Axes. Drilling down the chart over the date hierarchy, I would like to display a different measure per drillthrough level. Such that, drillthrough level (1) date[year] displays measure A, (2) date[month] displays measure B, (3) date[week] displays measure C.

Appreciate any help on this issue a lot.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The following appeared working for me and provides a unique measure per drillthrough level:

Measure_PAR = IF(ISFILTERED(Query1[Date].[Year]) && ISFILTERED(Query1[Date].[Month]) 
&& ISFILTERED(Query1[Date].[Week]), Measure C
,IF(ISFILTERED(Query1[Date].[Year]) && ISFILTERED(Query1[Date].[Month]), Measure B
,IF(ISFILTERED(Query1[PRODUCTIONDATE].[Year]), Measure A)))

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in the traditional drill-down options using hierarchy. You will just be able to drill-down into the next level of hierarchy for the same measures. But, you can do a version of your desired output using Cross-report drill-through. You will have to create 3 report pages in this case, one for each level and then you can use the drill-through to report option to get the desired result:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-cross-report-drill-through

This may not be the exact solution you are looking for, but I believe this is the best possible solution for your request. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I was thinking of taking together measures A, B and C into one parameterized measure X. Say, when drillthrough level = "Year" then X = A, when "Month" then X = B, else X = C.

Comment: That's an interesting approach. Check out this link, if you want to capture the drill-down level. https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Get-drill-down-hierarchy-level-from-Axis-on-column-chart-with/td-p/269554

Comment: It looks like your approach could work...I didn't think of it....Let me know if you run into any challenges

Comment: Thanks again. The aforementioned approach appears not working for me right now. I am using the following statement:

Custom_column = if(isfiltered('Query1'[Date].[Year]), Query1[BPPLH per year]
, IF(ISFILTERED('Query1'[Date].[Month]), Query1[BPPLH per month], Query1[BPPLH per week]))

Comment: Regardless drilldown level (year, month, week) it takes 'BPPLH per week'. I should note that 'Custom_column' is a column and not a measure, Perhaps this could be getting in the way.